# iis HTTP redirect by using rules in the web config

Tags: .net, http, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

im trying to redirect people who get to a specific endpoint to my new one

my url right now is:

```
...../api/<name of old endpoint>/<id or parameter or what ever>
```

and im trying to move them to:

```
...../api/<name of old endpoint>/<name of new endpoint>/<id or parameter or what ever>
```

so far ive managed to move them to the new end point but not with the parameters after the "/" (they are stuck in the middle between the name of the old endpoint to the new one)

can you please help me write the redirect rule for it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the new URL schema you have here, but the following should get you started. This is an IIS rewrite rule which would be added to the web.config file. It may require some adjustments and some honing depending on your exact scenario:

```
<rule name="Old to New Endpoint" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^api\/(\w*)\/(.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/api/$1/newendpoint/$2" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

To see how this works and to further test/extend it, here is a sample on regexr: http://regexr.com/3e2ms

Comment: thank you very much! 
how does it know to take the info into $1 and $2?
my old url is /api/smscampaign and i need to change it to /api/smscampaign/new and in the case of parameters add them to the end of the string

Comment: In the regex `^api\/(\w*)\/(.*)$`, the parentheses pairs are capturing groups. They basically act like variables and can be used in the replacement. So you see two groups: one for `(\w*)` and another for `(.*)`, which map to `$1` and `$2`, respectively.

Comment: i think i need to go back to the basics with regexes :) thanks a lot

Comment: No worries. Feel free to respond here if you need more help. Good luck!